# How can I get source code from URL with SSL using Swift?

Tags: ios, ssl, swift, nsurl

I am trying to read a source code of a site from its URL.

Below is my code.

```
let myURLString = "https://theUrlOfTheSite"
let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)

var error: NSError?
let myHTMLString = String(contentsOfURL: myURL!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

if let error = error {
    println("Error : \(error)")
} else {
    println(myHTMLString)
}
```

It works for some site, but not for others. I get the following error

2014-12-21 19:11:54.032 MyPlayground[2912:345862] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)
Error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)"

I think it's because the site is https, not http. (I don't really know about this stuff but..SSL something??)

So my question is, what should I do to make my code work??

I searched for hours but I'm new to iOS and Swift, so no progress.

Do I have to make NSURLConnection or something? Because all I want to do is get the source code. Must be a simple job I guess..

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To determine if there is an error test `myHTMLString` for nil, not `error`. If `myHTMLString` is nil then handle the error. `error` is not guaranteed to be non-nil on a successful operation.

Comment: There is nothing special to do for an https access, just use either http or https as required by the site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but `myHTMLString` is nil. For example, if you `let myURLString="https://www.dropbox.com"` you can see what I mean.

Comment: I randomly put some public sites' URL and the ones that failed to get source code were dropbox.com, mobizen.com, box.com .. All https sites. Is it mere coincidence??

Comment: Some sites restrict access via requiring access security such as tokens or client-side certificates, you will not be able to access these sites. You should be able to access via your code any URL you can access via a web browser such as Safari.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. You were right, my code wasn't wrong. The problem was Xcode playground. It works perfectly on a real device, but won't work on a playground. And I wasted 4 hours because of this...